# Datanucleus exception adding new column to hbase table

Tags: jdo, hbase, datanucleus

I am using [DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/) with [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/). I had a table `user`. It contained 4 rows. Now I added a new column to the table. Now everytime I access any old `user` object which does not have this column DataNucleus throws an exception as it is trying to map the column with the property in the POJO. Is there no other way than updating the old 'user' objects with dummy data? My object mapping looks something like this:

```
@Persistent(columns={@Column(name="next_mail_timestamp", insertValue="#NULL", defaultValue = "#NULL", allowsNull = "true")}, name="nextMailTimestamp", cacheable="false", nullValue=NullValue.DEFAULT)
    private long nextMailTimestamp;
```

As you can see I have tried using `insertValue`, `defaultValue` , `allowsNull`, `nullValue`. But nothing seems to work.

The stacktrace looks like this:

```
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toLong(Bytes.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toLong(Bytes.java:453)
    at org.datanucleus.store.hbase.fieldmanager.FetchFieldManager.fetchLongField(FetchFieldManager.java:269)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingLongField(AbstractStateManager.java:2133)
    at com.kuliza.sitepulse.data.User.jdoReplaceField(User.java)
    at com.kuliza.sitepulse.data.User.jdoReplaceFields(User.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.replaceFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:1989)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.replaceFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:2009)
    at org.datanucleus.store.hbase.query.HBaseQueryUtils$2.fetchFields(HBaseQueryUtils.java:226)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.loadFieldValues(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:803)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.initialiseForHollow(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:210)
    at org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactory.newForHollowPopulated(ObjectProviderFactory.java:88)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.findObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:2794)
    at org.datanucleus.store.hbase.query.HBaseQueryUtils.getObjectUsingApplicationIdForResult(HBaseQueryUtils.java:221)
    at org.datanucleus.store.hbase.query.HBaseQueryUtils.getObjectsOfType(HBaseQueryUtils.java:168)
    at org.datanucleus.store.hbase.query.HBaseQueryUtils.getObjectsOfCandidateType(HBaseQueryUtils.java:80)
    at org.datanucleus.store.hbase.query.JDOQLQuery.performExecute(JDOQLQuery.java:271)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1766)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithArray(Query.java:1655)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.execute(Query.java:1628)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:221)
    at com.kuliza.sitepulse.service.DataService.getUserWithCredentials(DataService.java:111)
    at com.kuliza.sitepulse.service.AuthenticationService.getUserWithCredentials(AuthenticationService.java:46)
    at com.kuliza.sitepulse.controller.AuthenticationController.signIn(AuthenticationController.java:69)
```

and my method is (in `DataService.java:111`)(which throws the exception)

```
@Override
    public User getUserWithCredentials(String userName, String password){
        PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
        Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM " + User.class.getName() + " WHERE userName == \""+userName+"\"" +" && password == " +
                " \""+password + "\"");
        List<User> c = (List<User>)q.execute();
        pm.close();
        if(c.size() > 0)
            return c.get(0);
        else
            return null;
    }
```

I have actually added two new columns (`mailIntervalInMilliseconds`, `nextMailTimestamp`) which are both `long` and in the stacktrace I see its trying to convert the db column to `Long` (AFAIK)

Comment: Perhaps if you actually state the exception + stack trace then people would know better

Comment: @DataNucleus my apologies ... I have updated my post

Comment: and the exception itself ? i.e the type. Because Bytes.toLong javadoc doesn't mention throwing an exception (hence is incomplete and third parties can't guess what it is throwing)

Comment: @DataNucleus Its java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Released versions of DataNucleus HBase plugin don't currently support all modes of schema evolution. In particular the addition of fields/properties when they are of primitive types. However DataNucleus SVN does have support for this, so you could use that.

Comment: thanks for ur response. Do i need to build all the components under SVN repo or just 'core' module would suffice ? I am currently using datanucleus-api-jdo-3.0.0-m6.jar, datanucleus-core-3.0.0-m6.jar, datanucleus-enhancer-3.0.0-m6.jar, datanucleus-hbase-3.0.0-m5.jar, datanucleus-jdo-query-3.0.0-m3.jar

Comment: No need. All is built nightly, but you need to get latest of all http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2-nightly/